force stop pending sector reads on a WD drive
I have 5TB WD disk drive that hits 100% usage the moment it's plugged in, the culprit is a high pending sector count that's keeping the drive busy trying to read from bad sectors, I want to recover the rest of the data from the hard drive but I can't use it at all due to 100% usage. Is there a way to force the disk to give up on those read tries without wiping it? or at least a way to copy the rest of the data somewhere else?

Use a disk cloner that just reads a sector and copies it. This will require hardware not necessarily software

@Ramhound any suggestions?

I provided the only suggestion I have.  Use a hardware device to clone the HDD to another failing HDD.  Accept the fact that any process will further degrade the HDD. You also have to accept this process might fail. Questions seeking software and hardware recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.

"the moment it's plugged in" – In what OS? From bad to best: Some systems may try to mount the filesystem(s). Some may read the partition table automatically, but nothing more. Some(?) may read nothing until you command them to.

@Ramhound yes, but I don't know any. and, It's an external WD My Passporet drive so I think the USB is integrated into the PCB... I don't know if that's even possible...

@KamilMaciorowski on windows, but to be more specific, I tried ubuntu liveOS and mounting is the issue.

@OmarAbdul'Azeez - Do an appropriate amount of research on hardware to clone HDDs and pick one in your budget range. You will have to remove the drive from the enclosure. You failed to mention that fact. I really should have mentioned this was or is a external USB drive.
